# syncing the time in app with system time in Android

Tags: android, datetime

Iam developing an app where i have a time clock in it , now iam taking the time from System clock at on activity created and displaying it but this one is not updating when the system time changes..Is there any method for cupdating the time when the system time changes?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always subclass a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) and create a thread that keeps updating( every second) the view once you fetch system time.

```
    public class TimerActivity extends Activity {
       TextView hTextView;
       Date d;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            hTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
            MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();
            d=calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            hTextView.setText(d);
            myTimer.schedule(myTask, 1000, 1000);        

        }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
          public void run() {
              if(TimerActivity.this!=null && !TimerActivity.this.isFinishing()){
              d=new Date(d.getTime()+1000);
              updateOnUIThread(d);
              }
          }
        }
}
```